# how to change image when checking and unchecking the checked textview in android?

Tags: android

I am implementing the `listView` containing checked `TextViews`.
Problem is when I check one list item one image should be display and when I unchecked another image should display.

Comment: do you have try to put those code in onCheck event?.please update code here

Answer (score 0):

U could use a checkbox in listViwe and customize checkbox to display wat image when checked and unchecked.Try this:android:button="@drawable/selecter"..Here selecter s an xml file where u can say whivh image to be displayed at different.